# Detect when AVAudioSession is being "Ducked"

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer, avaudiosession

I'm working on a Podcast app.  This plays audio using the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` session type.  This does almost everything that I want it to do.  It pauses other playing music, it gets interrupted when a call comes in and generally works exactly as I want.

With **one** exception.  When higher priority audio gets played (for example, when running a turn-by-turn navigation app) the audio in my application gets ducked down in volume but continues to run.  This creates an awful blending of the two voices that isn't desired.  I would instead prefer for the audio in my application to pause during the over-played sound then continue again once it finishes.

I've tried changing the different AVAudioSession properties such as `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`, but these only change how lower priority sounds are blended with my application.  They do not change how mine is blended with higher priority sounds.  I also tried observing the `otherAudioPlaying` property of the `sharedSession` but this didn't fire changes when I these short clips get overlayed.

Is there any way to detect when the audio in my app is being ducked so that I could instead have it paused?  Or alternatively to prevent the audio of my app from being ducked so that it would treat these other sounds as interruptions?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `kAudioSessionBeginInterruption` and `kAudioSessionEndInterruption` ?

Comment: Yes, but the overlay ducking doesn't count as an 'interruption' as far as the AVAudioSession is concerned.  So these callbacks/notifications aren't fired.

Comment: You may want to file a radar with Apple about that then if you feel it should be.  In my opinion, it seems logical that it should be considered an audio session interruption.

Comment: Have you found solution for this problem.I am suffering from same...please let me know if so please.

Comment: The problem might be that once you get the ducking notification and stop your sound, your app gets halted and you can't observe the unducking notification. The system would need explicit support for that and since their seems to be none, I think there is currently no way to do that. I fired up a support incident to get an answer from Apple.

Comment: I've provided the solution below which requires iOS 9.

Answer (score 5):

This feature was added in iOS 9 and can be enabled by setting your audio session mode to AVAudioSessionModeSpokenAudio.  Other apps that speak such as navigation apps will interrupt your audio instead of ducking.

See:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessionmodespokenaudio

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer and should be clearly upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote to Apple DTS about this issue. Here is what I got back:

> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). Our
>   engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is
>   no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the
>   currently shipping system configurations.
>
> If you would like for Apple to consider adding support in the future
>   to allow/notify the background app to stop playing audio when the
>   foreground app chooses to duck other audio, then enable the background
>   app to start audio again after ducking completed, please submit an
>   enhancement request via the Bug Reporter tool at
>   http://bugreport.apple.com.

Seems that it's impossible right now unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I never did this, but I imagine you could use AudioSession services C function *audioSessionAddPropertyListener* to register your callback for kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying.

Be aware there's some confusion in "FLATDACTED" documentation and Apple DevForums about the possibility of all or some AudioSession C functions being deprecated "in the future".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I appreciate the help.  However, I've tried that both with the Obj-C and C API.  Neither produced the desired result of a callback when being fired during ducking.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into interruptions, and simply discard your audio session when interrupted, then resume it when the interruption ends, as follows:

In your ViewDidLoad:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

if ([self canBecomeFirstResponder]) {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Handle the notifications:

```
static NSInteger audioSessionActiveCounter = 0;

- (void)audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    AVAudioSessionInterruptionType interruptionType = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] unsignedIntegerValue];

    if (AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan == interruptionType)
    {
       DDLogVerbose(@"Session interrupted: --- Begin Interruption ---");
       // stop your session here with a setActive:NO

    }
    else if (AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded == interruptionType)
    {
        DDLogVerbose(@"Session interrupted: --- End Interruption ---");
       // resume your session here with a setActive:YES
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying is supposed to call back in any way - it may be that you have to poll this value on a regular basis.

It should return a non-zero value when other audio is being played on the device. This may not indicate that you are being "ducked" per se but it would indicate that other audio is mixing with your audio. Supposedly you would only be ducked if the other app set the kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck property of their Audio Session.

Regarding polling - yes, it may not be as elegant as a callback, but sometimes it is necessary and I suspect polling this value is a minor hit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In you `AppDelegate.m` Class and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function, listen the following notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioSessionInterruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
```

and outside the application launching method, implement the selector as

```
- (void)audioSessionInterruption:(NSNotification *)notif{
    NSLog(@"\n\nInterruption Notification :%@\n\n",notif.userInfo);
}
```

Hope this will work for you....